# Draw a triangle with 3 sides given

Tags: c#, winforms, math

I want to draw a triangle with only the 3 sides length. (In C# Winforms)

Example: S1(3), S2(4), S3(5) with SN(x) as the length of each side.

I've tried to do this and the result is not a right triangle but it looks like it.
For the first side i just draw it like a line. and after i triy to find the angle with Pythagore and the same for the second one, but i realised that if i enter (5,4,3) it's something else.I'm just try to understand how can i find coordinates of a triangle with only the length of the sides.

```
  Point a = new Point(0, 0);
  Point b = new Point(s1, 0);

  double y = (Math.Pow(s1, 2) + Math.Pow(s3, 2) - Math.Pow(s2, 2)) / (2 * s1);
  double x = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(s3, 2) - Math.Pow(y, 2));

  Point c = new Point((int)x, (int)y);
  e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, a, b);
  e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, b, c);
  e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, c, a);
```

That's the result:

[image: Result]

Can someone help me? because I think I don't understand how can I do this.

Comment: "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)"

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann No beacause it's a Propriety, Thank's will edit

Comment: You could calculate the intersection points between two circles on point `a` and `b` with radius s(4) and s(5)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is more a math problem. At point A you have the sides s1, s3 with opposing side s2. The cosine formula then gives

```
2*s1*s3*cos(alpha) = s1^2+s3^2-s2^2.
```

Now the cosine is the projection of the angle to the horizontal axis, so you should have

```
x = s3*cos(alpha) = (s1^2+s3^2-s2^2)/(2*s1)
```

and correspondingly

```
y = sqrt(s3^2-x^2).
```

For the test side lengths 3,4,5 this would give

```
x = (3^2 + (5^2-4^2))/(2*3) = 3
y = sqrt(5^2-3^2) = 4
```

producing the points for the rectangular triangle.

Comment: Nothing here is specific for rectangular triangles, I just corrected the order of x and y in your question.

Comment: How can you apply these points? I have the same problem, but I don't understand  the correlation maybe you could help.

Comment: Apply in what way? What correlation? The naming of the sides and side lengths?

Comment: I don't know how to find the coordinates of three side. I also have 3 sides and I have to drawing this triangle.

Comment: The procedure in the question along with the above correction produces coordinates for all 3 points of the triangle. You might want to rotate and translate the result.